# ExpandableListView last group's last child visible on screen event?

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistadapter

How can i get  the event that is written in title? I want to know if that `RawLastChild` is visible on screen or not.

How can i catch event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for expandablelistview to see the last element

```
mExpandableListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount
                    , int totalItemCount) {
                if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount>=totalItemCount){
                    //the last item is visible
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Are you sure it will show me last group's last child or every group's last child?

Comment: this will last group's last child visibility

Comment: i tried it the event fires when u reach bottom and go to top again. After first reach, every time i scroll top the event fires again. Also the first ifs you write is not related to answer rite. What are they? Did u copy code from your project ? (if(firstVisibleListItem<firstVisibleItem){
                    firstVisibleListItem = firstVisibleListItem;
                    ClassroomActivity classroomActivity = (ClassroomActivity) getActivity();

Comment: i tried it the event fires when u reach bottom and go to top again. After first bottom reach, every time i scroll top the event fires again. It should fire only when last child is visible.

Comment: Around 30 or sth, but it can change dynamically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101072/discussion-between-peeyush-pathak-and-mert-serimer).

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet will solve your problem. Tested and working fine!

```
expandableListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
            if (!absListView.canScrollList(View.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) && scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                //When List reaches bottom
                loadMoreData();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
}
```